# WPF AutoCompleteBox dynamic sorting

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, wpf-controls, observablecollection, wpftoolkit

I am using the WPF AutoCompleteBox and I have it working great, but one thing I would like to do is sort the suggestion list on the fly after each letter is entered into the primary TextBox.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I tried using an ICollectionView property with the DefaultView logic and adding SortDescriptions but it doesn't seem to phase the suggestion list.  To make sure my collection view sorting was working I put a normal ListBox control and an AutoCompleteBox control on the same window and bound both controls to the same observable collection with the same collection view and the normal ListBox control showed the items sorted correctly using the SortDescriptions, but the AutoCompleteBox list didn't have the items sorted.  It had them in the order they were added to the collection.

Thoughts?  Suggestions?  Has anyone done this?

Comment: Care to share your solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how @user1089031 done this, but here is working sample for anyone who could be interested in (**updated to @adabyron's comment!**):

**ViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication12
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};

        private readonly ObservableCollection<Item> source;
        private readonly ICollectionView items;
        private string searchText;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            source = new ObservableCollection<Item>
                         {
                             new Item {Name = "111111111 Test abb - (1)"},
                             new Item {Name = "22222 Test - (2)"},
                             new Item {Name = "333 Test - (3)"},
                             new Item {Name = "44444 Test abc - (4)"},
                             new Item {Name = "555555 Test cde - (5)"},
                             new Item {Name = "66 Test - bbcd (6)"},
                             new Item {Name = "7 Test - cd (7)"},
                             new Item {Name = "Test - ab (8)"},
                         };

            items = new ListCollectionView(source);
        }

        public ICollectionView Items
        {
            get { return items; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Item> ItemsSorted
        {
            get 
            {
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText)
                        ? source
                        : (IEnumerable<Item>)source
                            .OrderBy(item => item.Name.IndexOf(SearchText,
                                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            }
        }

        public Item Selected { get; set; }

        public string SearchText
        {
            get { return searchText; }
            set
            {
                searchText = value;
                PropertyChanged(this,
                            new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SearchText"));
                PropertyChanged(this,
                            new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemsSorted"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
        xmlns:wpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication12"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="500"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource viewModel}">

    <Window.Resources>

        <wpfApplication2:ViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication2:Item}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="Courier New" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <controls:AutoCompleteBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSorted}"
            FilterMode="ContainsOrdinal"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
            MinimumPrefixLength="0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5">

            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <wpfApplication2:SearchTextBindBehavior
                            BoundSearchText="{Binding SearchText,
                                                      Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        </controls:AutoCompleteBox>

        <ListBox Grid.Column="1"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="5" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you could notice I've add one custom behavior to `AutoCompleteBox` control:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <wpfApplication2:SearchTextBindBehavior
            BoundSearchText="{Binding SearchText,
                                      Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

This is because `AutoCompleteBox`'s own `SearchText` property is read-only. So here is the code of this behavior:

**SearchTextBindBehavior.cs** (**Updated**)

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace WpfApplication12
{
    public class SearchTextBindBehavior : Behavior<AutoCompleteBox>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSearchTextProperty =
                            DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSearchText",
                            typeof(string), typeof(SearchTextBindBehavior));

        public string BoundSearchText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(BoundSearchTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BoundSearchTextProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
        }

        private void OnTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            if(AssociatedObject.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                BoundSearchText = string.Empty;
                return;
            }

            if(AssociatedObject.SearchText ==
                AssociatedObject.Text.Substring(0,
                                           AssociatedObject.Text.Length - 1))
            {
                BoundSearchText = AssociatedObject.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: To make it all work you will need to add reference to the **System.Windows.Interactivity.dll** from the [Expression Blend 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801). This is just where `Behavior<T>` and a few its friends live.

If you have Expression Blend already installed, you already have all the SDK and there is no need to download anything. Just in case - on my machine the assembly located here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

And, finally, if you have some good reason to do NOT add reference to this popular official library, feel free to re-implemented this custom behavior in "the old way" via plain old attached properties.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While this is a nice example, it does not really answer the question, because there is no _dynamic_ sorting involved. I'd like to have items sorted by how early the searchtext appears in them.

Comment: Oh, that is interesting turn, @adabyron. I'll update the answer if I succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Sevenate! This goes quite some way towards solving the issue. However, with it in place, I can unfortunately no longer navigate through the suggestions with key up/down. 

On a side note: It might be possible to bind to the Text property instead of SearchText, thus avoiding the behavior. That is not a problem in itself however, I'm fine with behaviors.

Comment: @adabyron I've noticed this issue with up/down keys, may be I could manage this as well (will try). As for "instead of SearchText" - if you are talking about this - BoundSearchText="{Binding SearchText, ... this is just a property of the ViewModel class and not the AutoCompleteBox element. By bad - I should choose another name to prevent any confusion.

Comment: What I meant is, there is a Text property on the AutoCompleteBox, which can be bound TwoWay..

Comment: @adabyron I've updated the Behavior with a quick fix for solving up/down keys issue, but it still could behave "strange" in some cases (like copy/paste new text in it).

Comment: As for binding directly to AutoCompleteBox.Text in TwoWay mode - it looks like it works a bit different way since there are some additional logic involved, based from what I could see from decompiled source (take a look at the private method TextUpdated()  of AutoCompleteBox).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32174/discussion-between-adabyron-and-sevenate)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with, a slight adaptation of Sevenate's answer, so if you wanted to upvote, do that to his post.

I used a subclass (I had the `AutoCompleteBox` subclassed already for other reasons), which allows me to create a wrapper dependency property to get the readonly `SearchText` (=what the user entered via keyboard) to the ViewModel - instead of a blend behavior, which is a perfectly valid way, too.

The crux of the matter is that you should only apply the dynamic sorting upon changes of SearchText, not `Text` (=what is displayed in the `AutoCompleteBox`, will also change if a suggestion is selected in the dropdown). Sevenate's way to raise the PropertyChanged event of the readonly ItemsSource (`ItemsSorted`) is a nice and clean way to apply the sorting.

ViewModel:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class AutoCompleteBoxDynamicSortingVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly ObservableCollection<Item> source;

    public AutoCompleteBoxDynamicSortingVM()
    {
        source = new ObservableCollection<Item>
                     {
                         new Item {Name = "111111111 Test abb - (1)"},
                         new Item {Name = "22222 Test - (2)"},
                         new Item {Name = "333 Test - (3)"},
                         new Item {Name = "44444 Test abc - (4)"},
                         new Item {Name = "555555 Test cde - (5)"},
                         new Item {Name = "66 Test - bbcd (6)"},
                         new Item {Name = "7 Test - cd (7)"},
                         new Item {Name = "Test - ab (8)"},
                     };
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemsSorted
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) ? (IEnumerable<Item>)source :
                    source.OrderBy(item => item.Name.IndexOf(Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
    }

    public Item Selected { get; set; }

    // Text that is shown in AutoCompleteBox
    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }

    // Text that was entered by user (cannot be changed from viewmodel)
    private string searchText;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return searchText; }
        set
        {
            searchText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchText");
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemsSorted");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Subclass of AutoCompleteBox:

```
public class MyAutoCompleteBox : AutoCompleteBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Bindable property that encapsulates the readonly property SearchText.
    /// When the viewmodel tries to set SearchText by way of EnteredText, it will fail without an exception.
    /// </summary>
    public string EnteredText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EnteredTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnteredTextProperty, value); } 
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnteredTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EnteredText", typeof(string), typeof(MyAutoCompleteBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // synchronize SearchText and EnteredText (only one-way)
        if (e.Property == AutoCompleteBox.SearchTextProperty && this.EnteredText != this.SearchText)
            EnteredText = SearchText;

        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Controls.AutoCompleteBoxDynamicSorting"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myctrls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Controls"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"
        Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource viewModel}">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <models:AutoCompleteBoxDynamicSortingVM x:Key="viewModel" />

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Item}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <myctrls:MyAutoCompleteBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSorted}"
            Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
            EnteredText="{Binding SearchText, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
            FilterMode="ContainsOrdinal"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Actually, I should admit that despite the fact that I'm not a big fun of subclassing from UI elements - it looks like your solution is the only way to go here if we need a clean and simple code without glitches during copy/paste into the AutoCompleteBox field. So it will be fair if your solution will be marked as the answer to this question.