# What could be preventing my combobox dropdown from showing after app focus is lost?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox in a WPF app that has recently been refactored to use the MVVM pattern. An apparent side effect to this change is that changing focus to another application while the combobox dropdown is visible completely prevents the dropdown from being visible again, until the app has been restarted.

The ComboBox DataContext is set to my ViewModel, with its ItemsSource bound to an `ObservableCollection<String> SearchSuggestions`, and IsDropdownOpen bound to a property `SuggestionsVisible` in the ViewModel.

The desired effect is a search box with autocomplete suggestions. It should close if there are no suggestions in the ObservableCollection, if the user cancels the search, if the user runs the search, or if the user clicks away from the text field - either inside the app or outside it.

The ViewModel explicitly sets the SuggestionsVisible property to true or false based on whether SearchSuggesions contains any items after user input. This process continues to take place after this bug manifests itself, just with no visible change to the UI. Any idea why losing focus while the dropdown is open renders the dropdown un-openable for the rest of the app's session?

Here's how I have things wired together:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding SearchBoxVm}" Name="cmboSearchField" Height="0.667" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEditable="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" 
          PreviewKeyUp="cmboSearchField_OnKeyUp" 
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="cmboSearchField_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
          Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchTopics}" 
          IsDropDownOpen="{Binding SuggestionsVisible, 
          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          Margin="50.997,15.333,120.44,0" 
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="1" >

<!-- SNIP STYLING -->
</ComboBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SearchBoxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void ResetSearchField(bool preserveContents = false)
    {
        if (!preserveContents || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
        {
            Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
            QueryFont = FontStyles.Italic;
            Query = DEFAULT_TEXT;
        }
    }

    public bool OnKeyUp(Key key)
    {
        bool showDropdown = SuggestionsVisible;
        bool changeFocusToCombobox = false;

        if (keyInValidRange(key))
        {
            SearchSuggestions = GetSearchSuggestions(Query);
            if (SearchSuggestions.Count > 0)
            {
                SuggestionsVisible = true;
            }
        }

        return changeFocusToCombobox;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    bool _suggestionsVisible = false;
    public bool SuggestionsVisible 
    {
        get { return _suggestionsVisible; }
        set
        { 
                    // this section is still called after this issue manifests,
                    // but no visible change to the UI state is made
            _suggestionsVisible = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SuggestionsVisible");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<String> SearchTopics = new ObservableCollection<String>();
 }
```

The OnKeyUp() method is called by the MainWindow class ( haven't gotten as far as binding events to handlers specified in the ViewModel ), while but there's also a call to ResetSearechField from the MainWindow:

```
// Note: removing references to this event handler does not have any effect
// on the issue at hand... only including here for completeness
void window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchBoxVm.SuggestionsVisible = false; 
    SearchBoxVm.ResetSearchField(true);            
}
```

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to debug this, and haven't seen any internal state changes that might account for this. The NotifyPropertyChanged event is otherwise behaving as it did before, and the stack trace window isn't showing any exceptions having been encountered.

Setting the binding mode on the IsDropdownOpen property to 'TwoWay' in the XAML hasn't had any effect either. Lastly, wrapping the assignment to SuggestionsVisible in a Dispatcher call on the main thread has had no effect on the issue either.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe in a few words like yours work and how it should be?

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev - done, please see the third paragraph.

Comment: @the wpf dev dude - Interesting suggestion. I set the combobox height to 25 but it did not affect the appearance of its drpodown. I also tried playing with the MaxDropdownHeight property but that didn't help either.

Comment: There could be something else in your app that's triggering this. Are you able to reproduce this in a test project ? I've previously used something similar and it worked without any issues.

Comment: Try change height or try change layout panel. Use getter and setter instead: public ObservableCollection<String> SearchTopics = new ObservableCollection<String>(); and don't use those KeyUp things at all. Post a photo of your problem for others to see what exactly your issue looks like.

Comment: Are any exceptions being thrown when you try and open it? Is the ItemsSource being reset or garbage collected? Are the bindings breaking upon suspension?

Comment: The posted code seems OK. Post other parts of code related with this, maybe the code behind.

Comment: Shouldn't SearchTopics be a property instead of variable? Can you remove IsDropDownOpen, PreviewKeyUp and PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp to try to bottleneck the problem?

Comment: The SearchTopics member has already been converted to a property, but thanks for catching this! @NateDiamond You know, I don't even know how to check if the bindings are breaking, but it doesn't appear that the ItemsSource is being GC'd.

Comment: If you're debugging, check your output window to see if it says anything about any broken bindings.

Comment: It looks like the OnKeyUp event is the only place where you would set SuggestionsVisible to true.  Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the code, and then triggering your problem, and then seeing if you're hitting the code the code that sets it back to true?

Comment: @PocketDews indeed I have - the code that sets it back to true is being called, and the NotifyPropertyChanged is still being called. From there it's a black hole - it returns without any errors or exceptions but nothing has been updated on the UI.

Comment: Looks like there are no obvious signs that bindings are breaking - nothing in the output window, not even after I set the trace level to high on the elements in question...

Comment: are you shore when you come back to your page the SearchBoxViewModel is the same instance? as a very common mistake is to change the instance so the bind is stuck to the old instance and doesn't listen to the new notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BrMcMullin, since you have stated that:

> The desired effect is a search box with autocomplete suggestions.

may I ask, why do you choose to use standard ComboBox instead of specialized [AutoCompleteBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox%28VS.95%29.aspx) that is available in the [WPF Toolkit - February 2010 Release](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) and seems like was especially designed for your case?

You may have noticed that first link points to documentation for its Silverlight predecessor, but don't worry - **WPF Toolkit** library include fully functional official WPF port of AutoCompleteBox from Silverlight. There is more info about this "event": [AutoCompleteBox: Now with 100% more WPF](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/wpfautocompletebox/).

With that control your auto complete popup could looks as simple as:

[image: Simple WPF AutoCompleteBox sample]

or as complex as:

[image: Complex WPPF AutoCompleteBox]

So, if you will not manage to solve your issue with ComboBox's popup visibility, feel free to give a try to AutoCompleteBox. With it you could even leverage [dynamic sorting of your suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583487/wpf-autocompletebox-dynamic-sorting/17225524) if needed (just use answer from @adabyron).

Comment: This is fantastic - right tool for the job. Quite honestly I didn't even know this control existed. When looking for an appropriate WPF control I kept searching for things like "search box." It never occurred to me to look for "autocomplete box"

Comment: @BrMcMullin, yep it may be confusing probably because AutoCompleBox could be used in many more cases then just search box. Think about any text box in some form that user will fill more then ones and relatively frequently - auto completion of not changed values in some of them will be very handy.